# PHP to JS, parsing <script> into HTML

Tags: javascript, php

Im doing a small game. I transfer the necesarry game data to the client by constructing the data and then entering it into the HTML like this

```
  <?php
    echo "<script>";
    echo "window.gd = ".json_encode($manager->game, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK).";";
    echo "window.ships = ".json_encode($manager->ships, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK).";";
    echo "window.ballistics = ".json_encode($manager->ballistics, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK).";";
    echo "window.playerstatus = ".json_encode($manager->playerstatus, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK).";";
    echo "window.reinforcements = ".json_encode($manager->reinforcements, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK).";";
    echo "window.incoming = ".json_encode($manager->incoming, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK).";";
    echo "</script>";        
  ?>

  <!DOCTYPE html>
    blablabla
  </html>
```

I then use a lot of client JS logic to convert this server-gamedata into something i can use for the game.

The problem is that there is still the raw gamedata in those global JSs vars and a player could, in theory, access and see/alter it, either before my local scripts convert them (so he could cheat his own stuff or he could see the enemies stuff in more detail).

How can i prevent that or what would be the correct approach instead of the one im picking ?

Comment: The client can always cheat; the person playing the game is completely in control of their own browser.

Comment: @Pointy is right. If you want to make it harder to cheat then you can start by thinking about how important it is that they don't cheat (considering it's a game) and who your target audience is. If your audience is a bunch of 10 year olds then you can probably just not worry about.

Comment: No way around that using the current setup. JS will alway display if they use "view source". You'll just have to hope the user wants to be honest and play the game as is.

Comment: `he could see the enemies stuff in more detail` The only way to prevent this is to check serverside if the player is allowed to see certain details about the enemy. The enemy is out of view? Don't provide the position of their ships.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I think it's preferable to use AJAX to get the data instead to store everything in global variables, every time you need the data, you can GET it.

But, using JavaScript all the data is accessible using the console.

Comment: This is probably the best way, right here.

Comment: That won't help. The data is still available in the browser.

Comment: It is, but it's more work just to cheat a simple game. http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/beginners-guide-to-ajax-development-with-php

Comment: That's right @Quentin, you can see the data throw the connection and you can open the console to see the data, but it's not embedded into the source. I think the question is about to hide the data from source (avoiding store the data in global variables).

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using global variables, i suggest you to get those values from php/json output file (using AJAX get method) every time you need them in this case you'll be sure that the user has the rights and he will not be able to over-ride them from the console.

Comment: Unless you add some type of encryption and token/key exchange this can still be spoofed.

Comment: If he's using JavaScript, I'd assume he want's it 'live' so the user can interact with the items being displayed. The json, is so he can input those values into the JavaScript at the start of the level.